# Textarea does not respond well to padding

Tags: html, css, textarea, alignment, padding

So I was trying to align a textarea inside of a div using the `padding` property:

```
#content { 
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 80%;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 4em auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 790px;
}
```

But it appears that the sides are uneven even so:

[image: This is uneven on either side]

I was wondering how I could fix this so the sides are even?

> BONUS QUESTION: How can I make it so the text box is not scrollable if the text amount goes over the box size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the textarea set the border to 'none'. **Edit** - set padding to 0

```
textarea {
    border: none;  /*optional */
    padding: 0;
    height: 790px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

to remove the scrollbars add overflow: hidden

```
textarea {
    border: none;
    height: 790px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: hmmm... just realised that only worked in Firefox. Sorry! I'll keep trying

Comment: Thanks anyway! Especially for the bonus question

Comment: mmm.... It still doesn't work :( Oh well, it's fine. Here's a jsfiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/a2szx/

Comment: But... it's the same off-alignment!

Comment: Oops - forgot add the padding 0! I'm sure this is it now!!  http://jsfiddle.net/a2szx/2/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you always reset before adding ANY styles. Each browser comes with it's own set of 'defaults', so it can make your site vary from browser to browser (and add unwanted spacing, such as your issue).

Check this link http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

You can put that at the top of your main style sheet or as the first external to load.

Comment: **As long as you're wanting elements to be viewed properly across all browsers, yes.** *Otherwise I wouldn't recommend it.*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a2szx/3/ Perfect borders.. All I did was add a CSS Reset to all elements - but using `*` isn't the "proper" way because older browsers won't support it. Thus, the reset CSS.

Comment: thanks! I misinterpreted your answer for some sort of external library, for some reason. But this works too!